# How to plot a specific function in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this function:

[image]
and I want plot it, I think the result is a periodic function...

I tried this but got only one point  :(

```
x1=-50:0.1:50;
x2=-50:0.1:50;
plot(cos(sqrt(power(x1,2)+power(x2,2)))/(power(x1,2)+power(x2,2)));
```

where is my problem and what is the correct way?
appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That's a 3d plot, since there are two inputs `x1` and `x2`. So you've got to use [plot3](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) (or [surf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) as @EitanT points out, or any 3d plotting function).
2. You're now only plotting the pairs `(-50;-50)`, `(-49.9;-49.9)`,...,`(50;50)`, because you start from two vectors, you probably want to cover all the combinations. Therefore, use [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) (for higher dimensions, there is also [ndgrid](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html)):

   ```
   x1=-50:0.1:50;
   x2=-50:0.1:50;
   [X1, X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
   ```
3. You now use matrix operations, read through [this link](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) and you'll see that you need elementwise operations: `a.*b` instead of `a*b`, etc. `power(a,b)` is already the element-wise operation (the same as `a.^b`), matrix equivalent is `mpower(a,b)` or `a^b`.

   ```
   f = cos(sqrt(power(X1,2)+power(X2,2)))./(power(X1,2)+power(X2,2)+1);
   plot3(X1,X2,f);
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You need to plot it as a 3-D surface. For example, use [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html):

```
[X1, X2] = meshgrid(-5:0.25:5, -5:0.25:5);
F = cos(sqrt(X1 .^ 2 + X2 .^ 2)) ./ (X1 .^ 2 + X2 .^ 2 + 1);
surf(X1, X2, F)
```

Note two things:

1. You forgot the "+1" in the denominator.
2. I've reduced the range of x1 and x2 coordinates, for better visualization.

If the black edges look annoying and seem to clutter the plot, you can remove the edge lines by disabling the `EdgeColor` property (as user Shai pointed out):

```
surf(X1, X2, F, 'EdgeColor', 'None')
```

The final result should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: @EitanT - regarding resolution of x1 and x2, you can turn off edge color to avoid the "all black" surface: `surf( x1, x2, F, 'EdgeColor', 'none' )`